# Modifying files in asset folder of an APK using java programming language

Tags: android, apk

I have an .apk file. In the apk file I have a XML file in the assets folder. I want to write a standalone JAVA program (Not in android) to modify the xml file stored in assets folder of the .apk. Apk file is not release signed. Any idea how to do this ?

Comment: UnZIP the APK file. Modify the XML. ReZIP the APK file with the modified XML. Digitally sign the APK file. `zipalign` the APK file. Done.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks. If you make this as answer I will accept it. Is it possible to Sign and zipalign the modified app, using java? Should I ask this as separate question?

Comment: You would sign using `jarsigner` (part of the Java SDK). You would zipalign using `zipalign` (part of the Android SDK). Both are command-line tools. Whether your Java code runs those tools, or whether you limit your Java to just modifying the XML and handle the rest via a shell script or something, is up to you. My comment lacks enough detail that I do not feel that it warrants upgrading it to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the apk file and get the xml file then update it and use `zipaligh` tool in android sdk to make it .apk.